# The code block inside the regex while loop is working but doesn't show results until manually terminated

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop

I'm new to Perl and CS in general and just trying to write some bioinformatics related code for learning purposes.
I'm trying to loop through a text file to find all occurrences of a specific sequence($motif) using simple match operator and while loop, the program works fine when I define the $motif in the code itself, but when I use user-input, the code inside my while loop does work but not properly and it won't terminate either, and when I manually terminate it, sometimes it shows some of the expected results while sometimes all.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.28';


print 'Enter the file name containing the sequence:';

my $filename = <>;

chomp $filename;

open(SEQ, '<', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

$/ = ''; #to read the whole file at once as it'll stop reading only when an undefined character comes up

my $row = <SEQ>; #storing the sequence from file to a variable
chomp $row;

print "\nEnter the Motif sequence to be searched:";

my $motif = <>;
my $counter = 0;
chomp $motif;

while ($row =~ m|($motif)|g) {
    $counter++;
    print"\n";
    print "The motif's occurnce $counter ends at position ", pos$row, "\n";
}
```

The expected output is a list of all the occurrences of $motif but the program doesn't terminate and when I manually terminate it using `ctrl+c` it shows first 2-3 occurrences, and its not about the time like when I assign $motif a value in the code itself it gives out hundreds of matches in an instant.

If I assign the file sequence (which I'm searching in) to the variable `$row` directly in my code then also the while loop functions properly, but the loop is not working fine just when I take the input file name(`$filename`) and write it in `$row` and the sequence to be searched (`$motif`) from the user. Assign any one of those inside code and the program functions fine.

Comment: Note that redirecting the output of the program can cause the output to become block-buffered instead of line buffered, so it may *appear* like things are printed later than they are. `$| = 1;` will disable buffering on the default output handle (STDOUT).

Comment: Please add `$| = 1;` at first line of the script and see.

Comment: @ikegami I've updated the code and this time I made sure that it is exhibiting the problem I mentioned, and I also tried adding `$| = 1;` but the problem still persists.

Comment: @ikegami I understood what you pointed out in your first comment, the program was running fine as long as I assign sequence in the code itself, but I need the user to input both the file name and the `$motif` and when I do that it doesn't work. And  I don't why you're getting the "could not open" because all that part is working fine on my system, I have tried opening different .txt files and printed them and it's working fine. Also, I'm not piping them out to any other program or file, honestly I don't yet know how to do that, this is a simple program I'm running through command prompt.

Comment: @ikegami And rather than the program working fine I'm more curious about why is it working  the way it is when the user inputs data, like it would have been understandable that there's some obvious flaw in code if, when the user inputs both file name and motif and the output would have been incorrect or no output or some error but somehow the output is correct but incomplete and the loop runs infinitely and I get to see some results once I hit `ctrl+c`

Comment: @ikegami thanks for trying but what I've posted above is my complete script and the same code is showing anomalous behavior on my computer, and I don't know why. Also if you are still getting that "could not open" error make sure the TXT file is in the same folder as the PERL script, I know that's not something you would have overlooked but I still mentioned just in case.

Comment: @ikegami You can use any .TXT file but if want, use any of the two text files here (https://github.com/makshuf/files.git) and search up for sequence "ATTC"  (quotes not included) when prompted for motif sequence

Answer (score 2):

You've change the input record separator (`$/`) to '' (empty string) from the \n value it was before.
At this line: `my $motif = <>;` input is expected, and it will not end as usual with "enter" (the \n). This is where your program "get stuck". It wait till it get a EOF value (end of file). You can use Ctrl+d (or Ctrl+z in windows) to pass EOF value so program will continue.

`chomp` use it as well (input record separator), so it too will not work as expected (the 1st chomp will work fine as it is called before the change).
You should return its original value (even better to change it locally only).  You also set the input record separator to an empty string. You should set it to `undef` if you want to read file in "slurp mode".

You can read more here: [slurp mode - reading a file in one step](https://perlmaven.com/slurp)

Simple update to your code (make sure to delete the `$/ = '';` line):

```
my $row = '';
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    local $/ = undef;
    $row = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
```

Though I would not recommend doing it this way... probably better reading the file to an array of lines, and using some more modern way like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

I've made some small changes to your code and tested it successfully with [MT_mouse.txt](https://github.com/makshuf/files/raw/master/MT_mouse.txt).
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print 'Enter the file name containing the sequence: ';
my $filename = <>;
chomp $filename;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my @file_lines = <$fh>;
close $fh;

print 'Enter the Motif sequence to be searched: ';
my $motif = <>;
chomp $motif;
print 'Read ' . scalar(@file_lines) . " lines at file: '$filename'\nmotif: '$motif'\n";

my ($line, $occurrences) = (0, 0);
foreach my $row (@file_lines) {
    $line++;
    next unless $row =~ /\Q$motif\E/;
    my @motif_index = ();
    my $position = 0;
    while((my $index = index $row, $motif, $position) >= 0) {
        push(@motif_index, $index);
        $position = $index + length $motif;
    }
    print "Motif found on row#$line\tat position(s): " . join(', ', @motif_index) . ".\n";
    $occurrences += scalar @motif_index;
}

print "\nMotif '$motif' was " . ($occurrences ? "found $occurrences times" : 'not found') . " at file: '$filename'.\n";

__END__
```

Output:

```
Enter the file name containing the sequence: MT_mouse.txt
Enter the Motif sequence to be searched: ACCCC
Read 272 lines at file: 'MT_mouse.txt'
motif: 'ACCCC'
Motif found on row#4    at position(s): 41.
Motif found on row#9    at position(s): 19.
Motif found on row#11   at position(s): 40.
Motif found on row#23   at position(s): 8.
Motif found on row#33   at position(s): 3.
Motif found on row#59   at position(s): 1.
Motif found on row#61   at position(s): 31.
Motif found on row#65   at position(s): 37.
Motif found on row#83   at position(s): 3.
Motif found on row#98   at position(s): 22.
Motif found on row#115  at position(s): 48.
Motif found on row#122  at position(s): 26.
Motif found on row#132  at position(s): 49.
Motif found on row#133  at position(s): 36.
Motif found on row#173  at position(s): 21.
Motif found on row#183  at position(s): 21.
Motif found on row#188  at position(s): 52.
Motif found on row#199  at position(s): 7.
Motif found on row#209  at position(s): 51.
Motif found on row#228  at position(s): 28.
Motif found on row#230  at position(s): 43.
Motif found on row#247  at position(s): 45.
Motif found on row#249  at position(s): 53.
Motif found on row#269  at position(s): 11, 18, 39.

Motif 'ACCCC' was found 26 times at file: 'MT_mouse.txt'.
```

Comment: thanks, I'll read the recommendations but the above change in code doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MOHAMMADMAKSHUF I've did a brief test and it seem to work (solving to original problem of the while loop). If you're talking about a syntax error, I've edited the example so `my $row` is outside of the inner local scope.

Comment: @MOHAMMADMAKSHUF have you checked it?

Comment: @MOHAMMADMAKSHUF I've added and an alternative made by some small changes to your code. Tested successfully (added output to aswer).

Comment: the new script you gave does work, thanks for that and your time. But I still don't understand the anomalous behavior of my script, even though I tried the new edit you posted.

Comment: @makshuf remember the input record separator (`$/`)? You've change it to '' (empty string) from the \n value (or "\r\n" in windows) it was before. Now at line `my $motif = <>;` input is expected, and it will not end as usual with "enter" (the \n) but wait till it get the EOF value (end of file). You can use Ctrl+d (or Ctrl+z in windows) to pass EOF value so program will continue.